# Play Framework: thread-pool-executor vs fork-join-executor

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework-2.0, threadpool, actor

Let's say we have a an action below in our controller. At each request performLogin will be called by many users.

```
def performLogin( ) = {
    Async {
        // API call to the datasource1
        val id = databaseService1.getIdForUser();

        // API call to another data source different from above
        // This process depends on id returned by the call above
        val user = databaseService2.getUserGivenId(id);

        // Very CPU intensive task 
        val token = performProcess(user)

        // Very CPU intensive calculations
        val hash = encrypt(user)

        Future.successful(hash)
    }
}
```

I kind of know what the fork-join-executor does. Basically from the main thread which receives a request, it spans multiple worker threads which in tern will divide the work into few chunks. Eventually main thread will join those result and return from the function.

On the other hand, if I were to choose the thread-pool-executor, my understanding is that a thread is chosen from the thread pool, this selected thread will do the work, then go back to the thread pool to listen to more work to do. So no sub dividing of the task happening here.

In above code parallelism by fork-join executor is not possible in my opinion. Each call to the different methods/functions requires something from the previous step. If I were to choose the fork-join executor for the threading how would that benefit me? How would above code execution differ among fork-join vs thread-pool executor.

Thanks

Comment: If performLogin is the only piece of logic that uses that executor, and it's only executed in succession and never in parallel (by multiple users perhaps?), then no. Other than that, you may want to split it up into different async steps to let other logic have a chance to run in between: Future(databaseService1.getIdForUser()).map(databaseService2.getUserGivenId).map(performProcess).map(encrypt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't parallel code, everything inside of your `Async` call will run in one thread. In fact, Play! *never* spawns new threads in response to requests - it's event-based, there is an underlying thread pool that handles whatever work needs to be done.

The executor handles scheduling the work from Akka actors and from most Futures (not those created with `Future.successful` or `Future.failed`). In this case, each request will be a separate task that the executor has to schedule onto a thread.

The fork-join-executor replaced the thread-pool-executor because it allows work stealing, which improves efficiency. There is no difference in what can be parallelized with the two executors.

Comment: What I don't understand is the term "Work Stealing" you mentioned. In above code, as you explained you can't work steal anything. All need to be done as one block = one thread. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Basically, instead of threads sharing a queue that they take tasks from, each thread has its own queue. If its queue runs try, it will steal half of the work from one of the other thread's queues (this is an example, work stealing is broader than this). [This paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150220/files/pc.pdf) on the parallel collection framework is a good read on the topic.